# How to read value from json file and then use it in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

"I have a 'version.json' file in my project with the following content:

```
{
    "version": "0.0.120-gd14b39ad",
    ...
}
```

I need to implement the following script in my 'package.json':

```
"commandA": "pact-broker can-i-deploy -–version 12"
```

I want to make the version parameter dynamic - read the value from the JSON file and then use it as a command argument. How can I achieve this?

I have made javascript to read value from JSON file but how can I can pass result als argument?